# Laravel Filter Not Working

Tags: laravel, csrf

For some reason the CSRF is not working, is not redirecting:

here is the filter

```
Route::filter('csrf', function()
{

    if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token')) { 

        return Redirect::to('/')->with('errors', 'request failed!');

    }

});
```

And Here is my route

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'crsf'), function() {

    Route::get("/Token", function() {

        $different = (Session::token() != Input::get('_token')) ? "IS DIFFERENT" : "IS EQUAL";

        $token = Session::token();
        $input = Input::get("_token");

        $equals = ($token == $input) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";

        return Response::json(array(
                    "session_token" => $token,
                    "input"     => $input,
                    "diff"      => $different,
                    "equals"    => $equals
       ));

   });

});
```

The Response shows that the result of the comparison between the Session token and the Input (which is NULL) is FALSE, they are different but the filter is not redirecting.

Comment: Try removing the if statement and leaving a only a redirect on the filter just to see if the filter is getting invoked.

Comment: Nope, It's not even being Invoked

Comment: Yup, that is because you are not invoking it.

Comment: In Fact, I've just discovered that the Route::group is the one NOT Working, when I use the filter outside the Group it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'crsf'), function() {
```

It should be:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf'), function() {
```

Comment: Omg, this happens so often